# Monitoring a Host/Port with Jenkins

Tags: shell, command-line, jenkins, sh

I am currently trying to monitor if a Host/Port is open (it's an Informix DB - but I don't think it's relevant). 
I have tried several approaches with the main idea to use `nmap` and then `grep` the output - which will contain either `open` or `closed`.

The scripts **works locally, but not on Jenkins** - and I'm not sure exactly why:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

nmapOutput=$(nmap -PN -p 20007 193.230.133.49);

echo $nmapOutput | grep closed  1>/dev/null 
if [ `echo $?` -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Closed - failing";
    exit 0;
else 
    echo "Open - success"
    exit 1;
fi
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
set -x

nmap -PN -p 20006 193.230.133.49 | grep closed
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried ssh'ing into the server, then running it?  if so, then it should be producing some error if it is indeed failing.. post that.

Comment: while your ssh'd in, run some of the data producing segments separately from the cmd-line and make sure their generating the data you expect, i.e. `nmap -PN -p 20007 193.230.133.49`. Good luck.

Comment: One should write their jobs/scripts to be portable and ensure to test for application paths.

One also should also allow both nmap to store a file and jenkins to return that file as the results of your job. To do this use the -o flag for nmap to store the results to an output file then in jenkins ensure that the output file is included in the list of artifacts for that job and it will be archived according to the configuration for that job. 

A good reasoning for storing the nmap output as a job artifact in jenkins is having an audit trail for that executed job when performing the pentesting.